# Where Statement with Case based on Current Time

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008, case

I'm looking to create a Case statement so that,
If the current time is before 11AM, I want the information from yesterday as well as today.
If the time is after 11AM, I only want the information from today.

Here's what I have right now

```
FROM [EDC].[dbo].[DIM_DefectData] with (NoLock)
Where
Case
    When datepart(hh, GetDate()) < 11 then
        [InitiateDt] > DATEADD(day, DATEDIFF(day, 0, GETDATE()),-1)
    Else
        [InitiateDt] > DATEADD(day, DATEDIFF(day, 0, GETDATE()),0)
End
```

And ....(additional requirements which are working)

Answer (score 0):

If I understand your problem correctly, the following is you want:

```
FROM [EDC].[dbo].[DIM_DefectData] WITH (NOLOCK)
WHERE [InitiateDt] > ( 
    CASE
    WHEN DATEPART(HH, GETDATE()) < 11 
    THEN DATEADD(DAY, DATEDIFF(DAY, 0, GETDATE()), -1)
    ELSE DATEADD(DAY, DATEDIFF(DAY, 0, GETDATE()), 0)
    END )
```

I placed the `[InitiateDt]` near by the `WHERE` clause.

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
select * from yourTable   
        where [InitiateDt] > Case When datepart(hh,getdate()) <11
                             Then dateadd(day,datediff(day,0,getdate()),-1)
                             Else dateadd(day,datediff(day,0,getdate()),0)
                             END
```

Comment: Thank you! Appears to work. Excited to test fully tomorrow.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
DECLARE @t table(d datetime)

insert @t values
('2016-08-30 09:00'),
('2016-08-30 10:00'),
('2016-08-31 10:00'),
('2016-08-30 11:00'),
('2016-08-30 11:08')

if(DATEPART(HH, GETDATE()) < 11)
SELECT CAST(d AS TIME) FROM @t
WHERE CAST(d AS TIME) <= CAST('11:00' AS TIME)
ELSE
SELECT CAST(d AS TIME) FROM @t
WHERE CAST(d AS TIME) > CAST('11:00' AS TIME)
```

The above returns all today's data as well yesterday before 11:00AM.